# Formatting not being applied CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The formatting will not be applied to my footer. I am not sure what the issue is. I have tried changing footer to a .footer but that doesnt' work either. The text in the footer should be aligned in the center and the color of the text should be black. The text is not centered and is blue because it is a link.

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size-adjust: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center center-block">
  <footer id="footer" class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
    <a href="/home/"> <img id="image" src="../images/Patriotonly.png" style="display:center" alt="Patriot Perspective" height="10%" width="10%"> </a>
    <span style="color: #161862;">Patriot</span><span style="color: #ED092C;"> Perspective</span>
    <div class="social_link">
      <ul class="sociallink_nav">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/patriotperspective/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ThePatriotPers1"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UColyEbi9qxlHLT0kpv46Tew"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/patriotperspective/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
      <ul><a href="privacypolicy.html" id="bottom-text">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="privacypolicy.html" id="bottom-text">Terms of Service</a>
        <a href="privacypolicy.html" id="bottom-text">Advertising</a>
        <a href="privacypolicy.html" id="bottom-text">Contact</a>
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2018 <a href="index.html">Patriot Perspective</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is an **obsolete element** and should no longer be used.

Comment: What are you expecting will happen? What specifically is not working? Bootstrap will override your CSS because there are styles applied to elements with more specificity.  *"I tried changing footer to a .footer but that doesnt work either"* Why? The CSS selector for `id="footer"` is `#footer`. I'd suggest reading up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps link in Bootstrap too!

Comment: the text wont become white or center in the footer that is the issue. None of the #footer formatting will get applied.

Comment: Your CSS is being applied correctly.  Setting `color` doesn't override the color of *everything* inside the element,  more specific rules (such as the colors for link elements) will take precedence. Centering elements that are full-page-width, such as your list items, will have no effect (because they're already centered, because they're the full width of the page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `"id=footer"`. `footer` is a native tag in HTML5, you can include it in your css without the hashtag. On the note of your bottom_text, better to include this as a class.  IDs are really meant to be used once, whereas classes are intended to be reusable. You didn't include the css for the `bottom_text` class, but you can change the # to a dot.

Include `li` tags to properly list the items in the list. You can remove the underline/ change the appearance of the link  by including a `text-decoration` attribute.

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size-adjust: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

footer a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center center-block">
  <footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
    <a href="/home/"> <img id="image" src="../images/Patriotonly.png" style="display:center" alt="Patriot Perspective" height="10%" width="10%"> </a>
    <span style="color: #161862;">Patriot</span><span style="color: #ED092C;"> Perspective</span>
    <div class="social_link">
      <ul class="sociallink_nav">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/patriotperspective/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ThePatriotPers1"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UColyEbi9qxlHLT0kpv46Tew"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/patriotperspective/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="privacypolicy.html" class="bottom-text">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="privacypolicy.html" class="bottom-text">Terms of Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="privacypolicy.html" class="bottom-text">Advertising</a></li>
          <li><a href="privacypolicy.html" class="bottom-text">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2018 <a href="index.html">Patriot Perspective</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Small suggestion to the answer - text-decoration attribute does not affect the color. Probably you just wrote it quickly like that.

Comment: @Exu It was written quickly, I was thinking of removing the underline. Thanks.